# Finding datatype of given Input

Tags: java, c++, c

Today my friend attend an interview , in that he was failed to ans a question. The question was like this `Program to find the datatype of a given Input` He asked me and I was able to crack up to this

```
include<stdio.h> 
main() 
{ 
  char n; 
  printf("\nEnter a character: "); 
  scanf("%c",&n); 
  if(isdigit(n)) 
     printf("\nInteger"); 
  else 
     printf("\nCharacter"); 
}
```

But it will tell only integer or charector, how about for an inputs like float double. Can any one help me inthis. Here we can use any programming language.

Comment: Can you be more specific about you mean by "data type"? All input is `char`s, but I don't think that's what the question meant.

Comment: All inputs are character arrays. This question makes no sense.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski  no my question is If user give in put as 1 it should say integer , if input is 1.89 it should say float, if input is A it should say char

Comment: @immibis. , my question is If user give in put as 1 it should say integer , if input is 1.89 it should say float, if input is A it should say char

Comment: So which language are you talking about? Java, C++,and C are very different languages.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski., any language I understand basics of all three

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski I think it will be simple in C.

Comment: if language is c you can use sizeof(var) and depending on value return by this function u can find datatype for eg. integer if sizeof(var) return 4

Comment: C is not simple, change your tags then.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski K. . then tell me in java

Comment: I believe that you (or your friend) may have possibly misinterpreted the term *given input* as keyboard-input, where in fact, the interviewer may have meant that, given a function which takes a generic-type input argument, find the specific type of that argument. Of course, if that is indeed the case then the question is not suitable for C. In C++, you can use `typeid(arg).name()`, and in Java you can use `arg.getClass()`. In any case, the type of a keyboard-input is always a null-terminated string.

Comment: @GaneshP can I read var as char?

Comment: @barakmanos , can you please give me an example

Comment: @Raghavendra: Just did, but it's not gonna stay there for too long (for obvious reasons)...

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you (or your friend) may have possibly misinterpreted the term *given input* as keyboard-input, where in fact, the interviewer may have meant that, given a function which takes a generic-type input argument, find the specific type of that argument. Of course, if that is indeed the case, then the question is not suitable for C.

**In C++, you can use the `typeid` keyword. For example:**

```
void func(const Object& arg)
{
    cout<<typeid(arg).name();
}
```

**In Java, you can call the `getClass()` method. For example:**

```
void func(Object arg)
{
    System.out.print(arg.getClass());
}
```

Comment: K thank u ., I got ur point . cant v do it for keyboard input.?

Comment: @Raghavendra: No. What would you consider 120? It can be a `char`, a `short`, an `int`, an `unsigned int`, a `long long`, etc. In fact, it can even be a string with the contents of `"120"`. Another example - what would you consider `c`? It can be a `char` or a string which contains one character.